# Как установить android sdk 25 на windows

Tags: android-sdk

Нужно именно отдельно, без андроид студии.
Сейчас с официального сайта можно скачать  только command line tools и для  виндовс это будет tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip
Т.е.  это папка tools из android sdk.
А что с ней делать то? Идея ее как папку для сдк не воспринимает, говорит инвалид.
сдк мэнеджер из подпапки либ - работать не желает.

Как  то я раньше устанавливал, забыл как, и сейчас что-то ничего не выходит, выручайте..

Comment: а просто распаковать в папку где лежит вся остальная СДК пробовали?

Comment: У меня есть только JDK, явно не туда..  где же может быть вся остальная СДК?

Comment: например C:\Android\

Comment: А откуда возьмется эта папка?

Comment: @Lazy Wolf Дык ежели пытаешься через IDEA, то AVD Manager, что пишет? Вообще через AVD Manager по идее можно установить, что тебе по душе. Без установки Studio.

Comment: AVD manager входит в состав android sdk (как я понимаю, так как в идее без андр сдк я его не нахожу). А так как не ставится сдк то и авд не пашет

Comment: Не понятно, как не ставится?! Вообщем почитай [тут](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). Там в самом низу есть отдельно sdk tools. Выбираем операционную систему и скачиваем. Усё. Делов то.

Comment: @Lazy Wolf Пути окружения настроить не забыл?

Comment: Именно это я скачал, и совсем не понятно что с этим скачанным архивом делать.  там нет установочного файла, а сдк менеджер оттуда не работает (и не должен)

Comment: java_home все дела...

Comment: попробовал скачать на компьютер где уже все установлено (android sdk) эту tools, история таже. просто не понятно что делать дальше...

Comment: @Lazy Wolf Почитай [тут](https://andreyklimenko.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/intellij-idea-and-android-sdk-installation/) затем напиши, что не получилось.

Comment: это старый туториал, раньше эти тулсы с установщиком скачивались, а сейчас без него

Comment: @Lazy Wolf AVD Manager начнет работать, когда создашь Android Project.

Comment: android project нельзя создать без сдк, ругается

Comment: Вот только проблемы с Windows

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, надо запускать файл android.bat  Я на самом деле пробовал его раньше запустить, но так как переменные среды еще не были добавлены, он не срабатывал...

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, весь список необходимых переменных, и что в них должно быть. Тогда ваш ответ будет полезен для других пользователей сайта.